# Cosa significa "taglio risorgimentale" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto:

> Con quel tempo da lupi, anche i fascisti del Corpo delle Truppe Volontarie erano alle perse, sebbene possedessero un dispiegamento esagerato di mezzi. Le divisioni, tutte agli ordini del generale Roatta,  erano: la 'Dio lo vuole!', la 'Fiamme nere', la 'Penne nere' e la 'Littorio', guidata da Annibale Bergonzoli, uno che aveva fatto la campagna d'Africa e che il Duce chiamava 'Barba elettrica' per via del **taglio risorgimentale**, visibilissimo a un miglio per la sua giacca a vento bianca a mo' di spaventacchio.

Il brano fa riferimento alla guerra di Spagna. Non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "taglio risorgimentale" che appare in questo brano. Immagino che il "taglio" abbia qualcosa a che vedere con il modo in cui era tagliata la barba di questo Annibale Bergonzoli, ma non so cosa vuol dire che era "risorgimentale". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: La tua deduzione è corretta: si riferisce al taglio della barba - non so come sia il taglio "risorgimentale" (il Risorgimento è quel periodo della storia italiana appena precedente all'unità d'Italia - quindi siamo circa a metà del XIX secolo) Immagino sia una barba folta e lunga almeno guardando come esempio un ritratto di Garibaldi (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Giuseppe_Garibaldi_1861.jpg)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: So cos'è il Risorgimento, questo non è il problema. Ed ecco l'aspetto di Annibale Bergonzoli:  https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annibale_Bergonzoli. Anche qui:   https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Campaign_in_North_Africa_1940-1943-_Personalities_E2294.jpg.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: L'articolo di Wikipedia dice che era soprannominato "Barba elettrica", ma non spiega perché.

Comment: @Gio: Quindi, semplicemente barba con baffi?

Comment: "Elettrica" potrebbe significare che era ispida?

Comment: Grazie, @Gio: non so perché non avevo visto questa spiegazione su Wikipedia.

Comment: @Gio: Penso che il contenuto dei tuoi commenti possa essere convertito in una risposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il “taglio risorgimentale” era caratterizzato da barba e baffi folti molto curati come descritto dal sito [gentlemenschoice.it](https://gentlemenschoice.it/breve-fenomenologia-della-barba/):

> *“La storia più moderna ha alternato differenti stili e tagli, fino ad arrivare alla totale riscoperta del baffo e della barba, come ad esempio il trend del periodo risorgimentale, in cui il pelo è diventato un simbolo di aristocrazia reale.”*

[image]

Per quanto riguarda Annibale Bergonzoli, l’appellativo  di “barba elettrica” sembra dovuto al suo temperamento dinamico e coraggioso:

> ”Rimpatriato in Italia per curarsi, divenne molto popolare tra i suoi uomini per via della fluente barba, tanto da meritarsi l’appellativo di "Barba elettrica",soprannome assegnatogli anche per il dinamismo e il coraggio dimostrato in combattimento.

([Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annibale_Bergonzoli))

[image]